# BIND Problems with connection refused

Tags: bind

```
host -l mycity.example.com
;; Connection to 10.0.1.12#53(10.0.1.12) for mycity.example.com failed: connection refused.
```

Here is my named.conf.options file:

```
acl "trusted" {
    10.0.1.0/16; 
    localhost;
    localnets;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    allow-query { any; }
    allow-query-cache { trusted; }
    listen-on { 10.0.1.12; };
    allow-transfer {trusted; };

// If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
// to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
// ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

// If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
// nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
// Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
// the all-0's placeholder.

forwarders {    
    10.0.1.1;
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
};

//========================================================================
// If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
// you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
//========================================================================
dnssec-validation no;


auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

FYI, only internal servers can get at this nameserver.

What am I doing wrong?? :(

More info from Bind9 status:

```
Apr 26 00:37:12 myserver1 named[15933]: client 10.0.1.12#38844
(myserver2.mycity.example.com): bad zone transfer request:
'myserver2.mycity.example.com/IN': non-authoritative zone (NOTAUTH)
```

Comment: What were your other files set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the answer is simple:
When using the host command with the -l option you do not use a host name as the parameter. You use a fully qualified domain name and then it returns all of the hosts. Once I entered the command as follows, everything worked as expected:

```
host -l mycity.example.com

server1.mycity.example.com
server2.mycity.example.com
```